# Printing lists in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, list, office-integration, word, printing

Is there a way to easily export SharePoint 2010 lists with rich HTML columns to Word 2010 for printing? Here's what we need:

- A "Print List" or similar functionality in SharePoint (IE browser), where the user can click it and have Word pop up with the list displayed.
- Convert certain list columns to outline items in Word, so a table of content can be easily generated.
- HTML rich columns not be displayed as raw HTML but as actual rich content (the one you get if you do Paste > Special in Word).

Is this possible? What do you recommend for a free/commercial product to enable this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use an alternate CSS to modify the print view of SharePoint pages.  By stripping out much of the SharePoint specific stuff, and using special tags in your HTML columns you may be able to load it successfully into word (or just print directly).

Some custom options to get to word:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/8aa3fa6d-2078-4bf7-ad9d-1ff5e689ecce

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/dmahugh/XML-Mapping-with-Word-and-SharePoint-part-2

Printing directly from list

http://spprintlist.codeplex.com/

http://store.bamboosolutions.com/p-119-list-print.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Jesus. Very nice list. One addendum: The SPPrintList is only for SP 2007 -- it won't work on 2010.

Comment: I missed the big bold labeling :)  The project has not been updated in a while, if you so desired you may be able to make it compatible with 2010 as the source is available.

Answer (score 1):

Alex,

Unfortunately the method I am proposing does not work with enhanced rich text fields (e.g., HTML, tables, etc.), but I use it successfully with most other field types.

1. Export the list or library to Excel.
2. Create a data connection to the list or library so that the workbook automatically syncs with list updates when opened.
3. Format the workbook for printing.
4. Save the workbook to SharePoint for users.

For step-by-step instructions view my post at https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2015/03/28/print-live-list-or-library-data-from-excel-workbooks-using-data-connections/.